# Calculating Arc Angle In Java

Tags: java, graphics, awt, angle

when i right click on the the Jframe this pie appears. what i want is to calculate the angle of each pie when click event occurs.

```
 Color[] c = {Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, 
                     Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.PINK};
        for(int i=0; i<8; ++i){
            g.setColor(c[i]);
            g.fillArc(x, y, w, h, i*45, 45);
        }
```

here what i have tried

```
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {


              PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
               Point d  = a.getLocation();
               x1 = (int)d.getX();
               y1 = (int)d.getY();
               int base=x1-CenterX;
               int prep=CenterY-y1;
               double tan=prep/base;
               double angle=Math.atan( tan);
  }
```

but the calculted angle is not correct. it some times give me divide by zero exception. 
and here is my right click event which shows the menu.

```
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.isPopupTrigger())
            {
                CenterX=e.getX();
                CenterY=e.getY();
              try {
                    Thread.sleep(300L);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(animate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
        p.repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.isPopupTrigger()){
               s=e.getX();
                as=e.getY();
                p.mx=e.getX(); 
        p.my=e.getY();
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: [`PointerInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html#getLocation()) provides the mouse's location with respect to the entire screen, not your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a divide by zero will happen if `base == 0`, ie if `x1 == CenterX`.

use [Math.atan2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29).  It converts x/y coordinates to angles and takes care of all of the messy math for you.